# typescript definition for react-router v2.0 - error `has no exported member 'browserHistory'`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-router, tsd

I am using [react-router v.2.0.0.-rc3](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/v2.0.0-rc3) and typescript. I installed the definition file via [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd). Since they [changed the `browserHistory`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#using-browser-html5-pushstate-history) from beeing a mixin to a module, I get the error `Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'browserHistory'` on my terminal when compiling the javascript via webpack. Is there an easy way I can modify the `react-router.d.ts` file to fix the error? Or do I just have to wait until they update the definition file? My app is working fine, it is just the console-error that bugs me.

Comment: Sorry missed the typescript part! Do you need middleware to import any JS module in typescript!?

Comment: yes, the current file for react-router is here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react-router/react-router.d.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome [James Brantly](https://github.com/jbrantly) pointed out that there is already an [pullrequrest](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/7449/commits) for v2.x. I used and all the errors are gone!

Answer (score 0):

Installing the version 3 of the types solved the problem.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react-router@3.0.19
```